# Display Thread name when debugging - delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging

I've found some good questions and with good answers for naming threads in Delphi.
Like this one [Named threads in Delphi - what is that for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864306/named-threads-in-delphi-what-is-that-for).

But how, while debugging, I get to see the name of the thread?
And also, even with that, I cannot see the thread name in utilities like Process Explorer right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the execution is paused (because you trigger the pause by clicking the "pause" icon or selecting menu Run, Program Pause; or because the breakpoint is hit), the thread names are visible in the Threads window (View, Debug Windows, Threads; or Ctrl-Alt-T).

No, Process Explorer cannot show thread names.

Comment: Thanks @gabr. I guess I will have to go for a dictionary solution (threadID=threadNAME)