# Is this the correct way to set a thread's name in Delphi 6?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, exception

I want to have a nice user friendly name appear in the thread list window while in the Delphi 6 IDE.  I found the code below on the web for doing this in Delphi 6 since as far as I know that version does not have SetThreadName() implemented natively.  I call it from my thread's Execute() method.  I know it's being called because the IDE pops up when the Exception is raised.  However, when I look in the thread list (Ctrl + Alt + T), I don't see the name I set.  I just see the usual Thread Id, State, Status, and Location columns, nothing else.

What do I need to do differently to get the thread names to appear?  Also, does anyone have an idea on how to stop the IDE from pausing on the RaiseException line?  I have a lot of threads in the program and it's annoying to have the IDE popping up N times every time I run the program.
I know I can disable the IDE from stopping on Delphi Exceptions, but I want that normally and I'd prefer not to have to toggle that off and on every time a new set of threads is created.

[Named threads in Delphi - what is that for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864306/named-threads-in-delphi-what-is-that-for)

```
procedure SetThreadName_delphi(const Name: string);
    type
      TThreadNameInfo =
        record
          RecType: LongWord;
          Name: PChar;
          ThreadID: LongWord;
          Flags: LongWord;
        end;
var
    info:TThreadNameInfo;
begin
    // This code is extremely strange, but it's the documented way of doing it!

    info.RecType := $1000;
    info.Name := PChar(Name);
    info.ThreadID := $FFFFFFFF;
    info.Flags := 0;

    try
        RaiseException($406D1388, 0,
        SizeOf(info) div SizeOf(LongWord), PDWord(@info));
    except
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I believe that the thread name is only visible in Delphi 2010 and above.

Comment: No, thread naming has been supported since D6.

Comment: Scratch that - Delphi 7.

Comment: Very useful piece of code! Works for me in XE. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The NameThreadForDebugging mentioned by Remy works equally well.

Comment: While this is correct for Delphi versions 7-2007 but the name field of the record should be PAnsiChar in order to support newer Delphi editions as well.

Answer (score 6):

I have found [the original code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx)

It is an application-specific exception (that means it is specific for Visual C++ compiler). I see no reason why Delphi should support this strange feature (though it is possible).

---

*Edit* : **BUT IT WORKS!** (Thanks to Remy Lebeau)

Just tested on Delphi XE (I see 'Wow!' in the debugger 'Thread status' window):

```
unit NameTest;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes;

type
  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TTestThread }

procedure SetThreadName_delphi(const Name: string);
    type
      TThreadNameInfo =
        record
          RecType: LongWord;
          Name: PAnsiChar;
          ThreadID: LongWord;
          Flags: LongWord;
        end;
var
    info:TThreadNameInfo;
    AnsiName: AnsiString;

begin
    AnsiName:= Name;
    info.RecType := $1000;
    info.Name := PAnsiChar(AnsiName);
    info.ThreadID := $FFFFFFFF;
    info.Flags := 0;
    try
        RaiseException($406D1388, 0,
        SizeOf(info) div SizeOf(LongWord), PDWord(@info));
    except
    end;
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  SetThreadName_delphi('Wow!');
  while not Terminated do
    Sleep(1000);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thread naming was introduced In D6, and uses the exact same exception that Visual Studio does..

Comment: It uses the same magic exception so that the delphi debugger can show the names of threads named in dlls coded in msvc.

Comment: `TThread` has a static `NameThreadForDebugging()` method, which was introduced in D2010, so you do not need to call `RaiseException()` manually anymore (and it can be used with non-`TThread` based threads), eg: `procedure TTestThread.Execute; begin NameThreadForDebugging('Wow!'); ... end;`

Comment: @Serg - I just tried your code, which only seems to differ from the snippet I posted by the use of PAnsiChar(AnsiName) instead of PChar(Name), and I still *don't* see the thread names (Delphi 6).

Comment: @RobertOschler Thread Name should be in 'Thread Id' column. I tested the code on Delphi 2009 & 2007 too, and it works. Sorry, no Delphi 6.

Comment: @Serg - Thanks for testing that.  All I see in the Thread Id column is the hex ID value of the thread.  Something else must be wrong I guess.

Comment: I did some more research. **C++Builder** v6 supports thread naming (I use that myself all the time), but **Delphi** v6 does not, even though they share the same RTL and VCL. That feature was added in **Delphi** v7.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB - Ok, thanks for checking that out.  Talk about just missing the cutoff by a nosehair.  I stayed at D6 because I heard D7 had certain problems, maybe I should have upgraded.

Answer (score 6):

In C++Builder 6 and Delphi 7 onwards, the `File > New > Other > Thread Object` wizard has an option for naming the new thread in the debugger. The wizard generates a stub `TThread` descendant class with the necessary `RaiseException()` implementation at the top of its `Execute()` method.

That is not any help for Delphi 6 though, which did not support thread naming yet.

Comment: I just tried that and the only thing in the generated Execute() method was the comment "Place thread code here".

Comment: Also,  I just tried Serg's code, which only seems to differ from the snippet I posted by the use of PAnsiChar(AnsiName) instead of PChar(Name), and I still *don't* see the thread names (Delphi 6).

Comment: Apparently it was not implemented until Delphi 7, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment on the other reply and I am really grateful for your detailed expertise and help.